# Is there any benefits using flatMap over map in jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, big-o, flatmap

For example:

```
const Foo = ({ items }) => (
  <>
    {items?.flatMap(({ foo, bar }) => (
      <>
        <div>{foo}</div>
        <div>{bar}</div>
      </>
    )}
  </>
)
```

Can we guarantee that on output will be plain array?

Can we reduce Nesting Depth or simplify in Big-O?

Answer (score 1):

`flatMap` is only useful when the return value of its callback returns an array:

[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```
arr1.map(x => x.split(" "));
// [["it's","Sunny","in"],[""],["California"]]

arr1.flatMap(x => x.split(" "));
// ["it's","Sunny","in", "", "California"]
```

In this particular case when mapping into JSX the return value of the callback **will never be array** since React limits you to have only 1 root node.

Therefore, in this particular case no benefit from `flatMap` over `map`